# How to force my asp.net core uses http and not https

Tags: http, asp.net-core

I have seen this type of question asked but the other way.  namely to redirect http to https.

This my scenario.  I have a asp.net core app. I deploy it to my test server.
When I view in an eternal browser the js and css etc will not load up. Upon inspection it is redirecting everything to https.  I do not want this.

How can i force it to 'stay' with http?

Comment: force with redirection in iis

Comment: @JeePakaJP thanks but would be the setting?

Comment: yes check this link, change just https to http
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: @JeePakaJP thanks followed all of that.Did not work :( then realised that is redirecting http to https

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for a fix for the *actual* bug? HTTPS doesn't prevent loading Javascript and CSS. The ASP.NET Core templates use HTTPS by default and have no trouble with Javascript or CSS.

Comment: What bug? I can see via the inspector it is trying to load the resources via https.

Comment: Share us a screen shot about your web browser debug tool network tab.Do eos js and css in your project wwwroot folder? With commenting `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, it will not redirect http to https. Do you request https directly from client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in `Configure` method in `Startup` class.

And nothing would be via HTTPS unless explicitly requested.

Comment: Thanks.I have already tried that but it does not work, I read it is only to redirect http to https and not the other way round

Comment: Is there still something during the test that redirects to https?

Answer (score 5):

Goto project properties --> Debug --> uncheck Enable SSL

[image]

*One more hint:*

remove the schema from the URL, so it will load the referenced scripts and css files according the client's URL (http or https)

```html
<script src="//cdn.mysite.com/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: Thanks 1st thing did. Also, i am not using a schema.I am using relational paths